# Why does this render an empty plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to know why this python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
x = np.arange(-3,3,100)
y = -(np.arctan(-1/x))
plt.ylim((-1.5,1.5))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

renders an empty plot, with the axes having my desired limits. Wolfram Alpha assures me that the function should be visible within these limits.
I am completely lost here.

Comment: Your range is invalid. Try `numpy.linspace` instead.

Comment: What do you mean? The range for x?

Comment: Yep, do `x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)` and then it will be visible. Your range only contains `-3` and thus only a single point, which is not really visible.

Comment: @ThomasLang Add that as an answer

Comment: @lxop Added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range contains only a single point `x = [-3]`, hence you won't plot much.
What you want is to create a linear space using

```
x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)
```

Then your function will be visible.

Edit: Explanation of the first sentence:

```
np.arange(start, stop, step)
```

This will create a range starting at `start`, stopping at `stop` (exclusive) and stepping by `step`. Thus you start with `-3`, the next value must be at stride `-3 + 100 = 97`, but this is not smaller than `3`. Thus the range only contains the start number.

`np.linspace(start, stop, number)` instead will create a range in the interval `[start,stop]` divided equidistant in `number` partitions.